# Calculate md5 hash on the fly during download using AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, md5, afnetworking

I would like to be able to intercept the bytes coming over the wire using AFNetworking to be able to calculate a large file's md5 hash during download rather than waiting for download to commplete and then scan the file from the filesystem.

Is this possible? I use an NSOutputStream to write the file to the disk but there isn't a way to read from an OutputStream (on purpose), and the callbacks to update progress only contain the counts of bytes read and total bytes.

Any advice would be appreciated.